# Is there a way to show tree of .gitignore files used to compute final ignore list?

Tags: git

I want to know which .gitignore file specifies a particular rule.

From: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore:

```
Git normally checks gitignore patterns from multiple sources, with
the following order of precedence, from highest to lowest
```

Since git checks .gitignore files outside the current directory, sometimes it's not clear which of those external .gitignore files has the rule that's causing git to ignore some files.

Documentation and Google searches have been fruitless since every query just leads to "why isn't my .gitignore rule working" or "how do I remove files I checked in that are now in my .gitignore file" type questions.

I would really like to have something like:

$ git --show-me-all-the-.gitignore-files-you-are-using

```
/.gitignore
 <rules from /.gitignore>

~/.gitignore
 <rules from my user .gitignore>

/some/parent/directory/.gitignore
 <rules from that .gitignore file>
```

And so on, all the way down to the patterns read from the command line, $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, the file specified by the configuration variable core.excludesFile, and so forth.

A plain text output of all the rules, with duplicate rules removed, and in the correct final order would be extremely useful to produce a canonical .gitignore for a project.

This would make it possible to `build` a .gitignore for a project that perfectly duplicated *all* of the .gitignore rules used by the resultant repository.

Since global rules can exclude things that would not be excluded by a normal project-local .gitignore file, someone checking out the project could get different, odd seeming results when trying to check in their changes.

E.g. if **/build is specifiec in ~/.gitignore but not in the current directory's .gitignore, the build directory will not automatically be excluded by someone who has cloned the project unless the **/build rule is also (obscurely) specified by one of the rules from their particular setup.

Comment: You mentioned `checking out the project`. By `checking out`, do you mean `git checkout`? If `**/build` is checked out, then it's already tracked by the repository. Ignore-rules don't have effect on tracked folders and files.

Comment: Edited to specify 'cloned' rather than checked out.  If they clone the project, since my (inherited) rules excluded `./build`, it will not be in their clone.  If they then build the project (creating the `./build` directory), a `git status` will show `./build` as containing un-vcs'd files unless they also (opaquely) inherited a rule excluding `./build` as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool, though you could build one pretty easily: just use the documented search order to check for the existence of each file, and if that file does exist, list it, in the order.

There is, however, a tool that—while not what you are asking for here—is usually more useful.  Given an existing repository—one in which you are working right now—containing some set of work-tree files, you can run:

```
git check-ignore -v path/to/file.ext
```

to see:

1. whether there is some `.gitignore` with a rule that applies to the given file;
2. if so, which *line* of that file applies.

Note that `git check-ignore` will tell you about files that have specifically been *un*-ignored with a `!`-prefixed rule, so it's a good idea to use the `-v` option and inspect the actual rule.

Comment: "just use the documented search order" -- that's exactly what I'm hoping to avoid.  The git code already knows how to do it, and will always be up-to-date with itself.  Nothing worse than writing and coming to rely on a utility that starts (silently) returning wrong results due to implementation changes in the target tool.